# How to make Unity WebGL app placed on simple html page load asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, html, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, unity-webgl

I created a game in Unity and regularly exported it for WebGL.
The index.html page that comes with this export contains these parts of code:

script definition

```
<script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
<script> 
  var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/1.0.json");
</script>
```

and using of that script

```
<div class="gameContainer">
    <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 960px; height: 600px; margin: auto"/>
</div>
```

inside of plain html code.

Now I realized, that when I put more content on that page, everything freeze until the game is loaded.
What is the adequate solution for that?
Is there a simple way, how to make this game load async?

Thanks a lot for any answers!

Comment: Perhaps making the game load as the last thing might be a work-around if you can't get async loading to work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading it within your HTML, load it inside a javascript file (there are a few ways to do this asynchronously in javascript that I can google later and edit with references if needed). That way your HTML and CSS will load, you can have some sort of default loading image/gif, and your separate javascript file can display your game when it's ready.

Comment: Thaks a lot for your suggestion, I guess I'll figure out how to make it in a separate file. I was wondering if it is possible to make it directly in the HTML file. Or if there existed some superawesome tag that did the job for me :) but It seems like I would need to be good with this...

Comment: No problem! Actually now that you say that I remember a way to do async loading within the HTML file that I read when embedding a GoogleMaps widget into a webpage (I'd have to look up that tutorial again). It's not a special HTML tag but rather the same javascript that lets you load the resource asynchronously, but you can keep it in the <script></script> block of your html file if you wish.